# VS Code Live Share - errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-liveshare, vscode-liveshare

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio Code live share - errno 2 No such file or directory to more exact.

The error happens when my friend, who is connected to my collaboration session, tries to run the code on his side. The same happens when I connect to his session and try to run his code.

From what I understand from MS VS Code page and other websites, live share should allow us not only to work on the same code, but also run it on both machines.

We tried sharing a server but it also did not help - even though I had access to his other files, like a test HTML website which we created to check if sharing a localhost server works.

I'm kinda running out of ideas and do not really know what else we could do to fix this issue.

Could anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a shared terminal. Then at least you can execute things remotely on the host machine